# Logic and method to update a "like this" link via Ajax

Tags: php, mysql, ajax

I came back to view my question  and was told it had been "voluntarily removed by its author", but I didn't remove it!  So I don't know what happened there.  So now I've got to ask it all over again, and hope that this time it stays here!

I have a PHP scripted page which displays a number of images.  I'm setting up a method whereby a logged-in user can click a link below an image to "like" the image (make it a 'favourite') - or "unlike" it if it's already a favourite.  The current "like state" for the user is saved in a MySQL database (as 1 or 0).

My PHP page loops through the image records (along with some pagination logic), polls the database and outputs a different link underneath each image according to the "like state" that's returned.   One form of link is drawn for an already "liked" image, and another form for one that isn't "liked" (each using one of two different css classes to appear as rollover-type icons for the visual feedback).

It looks like this:

```
<?php
$step = 0;
while($row = $statement3->fetch()) {
$step++;
$ThisPhotoID = $row['photoid'];

echo '<img src="images/'.$ThisPhotoID.'.jpg" alt="" />';

echo '<div class="info">';
$statement4 = $db->prepare("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM `likes` WHERE `username` = ? AND `photoid` = ?");
$statement4->execute(array($username, $ThisPhotoID));
    if (!$statement4->fetchColumn() > 0) {
    //Favourite doesn't exist for this user, so invite to "like"...
    echo '<a href="#" id="linkid'.$step.'" title="Click to like this photo" class="like">&nbsp;</a>';
    }
    else {
    //Favourite does exist for this user, so check if already "liked" or not...
    $LikeState = 1;
    $statement5 = $db->prepare("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM `likes` WHERE `username` = ? AND `photoid` = ? AND `likestate` = ?");
    $statement5->execute(array($username, $ThisPhotoID, $LikeState));
        if ($statement5->fetchColumn() > 0) {
        //Favourite exists and it is liked, so invite to "unlike"...
        echo '<a href="#" id="linkid'.$step.'" title="Click to UNLIKE this photo" class="unlike">&nbsp;</a>';
        }
        else {
        //Favourite exists but it is not "liked", so invite to "like"...
        echo '<a href="#" id="linkid'.$step.'" title="Click to like this photo" class="like">&nbsp;</a>';
        }
    }
echo '</div>';
}
?>
```

This all works OK and draws the appropriate link for each image, according to whether it's "liked" or not.  At the moment the link references are just hashes, as I'm wondering how to do the processing to change the "like state".

I have a processing script ready, whose name I could put in place of the hashes, which could take the $ThisPhotoID variable in a query string, and update the database (switch the "like state") and then return to the page via a PHP header - maybe to an anchor.

That processing script would look something like this:

```
<?php
include("login.php");
$username = $session->username;

include('db_connect.php');

//This would be used in the link's query string...
$PhotoID = $_GET['photoid'];

//Get existing "likestate"...
$askstatement = $db->prepare("SELECT `likestate` FROM `likes` WHERE `username` = ? AND `photoid` = ?");
$askstatement->execute(array($username, $PhotoID));
$CurrentLikeState = $askstatement->fetchColumn(0); // Will be 1 or 0.

//Make new likestate...
if ($CurrentLikeState == 1) {
$NewLikeState = 0;
}
else {
$NewLikeState = 1;
}

//Change the like state...
$update_statement = $db->prepare("UPDATE `likes` SET `likestate` = ? WHERE `username` = ? AND `photoid` = ?");
$update_statement->execute(array($NewLikeState, $username, $PhotoID));

header("Location:mypage.php");
?>
```

But this isn't ideal, and I'm wondering if it would be possible to do the updating via Ajax, without leaving or refreshing the page, perhaps using JQuery.  As far as I can tell, to do this, I'd need to include JQuery, and:

- insert a js function
- insert a js onclick event in each link
- build the new form of the link in the processing file for the javacsript/ajax to use as the replacement link

It's the javascript/ajax code that I need help with, but also I'm a little confused as to how it could possibly work anyway - wouldn't the javascript/ajax have to draw my links in the first place, if it's going to change them after the database is updated?  (If PHP outputs the links, won't they just stay as PHP outputs them?)

Comment: I would recommend reading a tutorial on ajax using jQuery, I think it would help you out a lot.  You should print out your links with php and bind onclick events to those links.

Comment: I've been looking for examples of Ajax but I don't seem to see any employing this implementation - transforming the links after calling the processing script.  If anyone has any more specific code examples (the js function using the link IDs, the link onclick, etc) I'd be extremely grateful.

Answer (score 0):

Only because I don't really know how to comment on your question, I am providing this comment in this section. JQuery has two different functions that you could use, which are the `$.post()` and `$.ajax()`-functions.

you could class your links like this:

```
<a class="like_link" title="<?php echo $picture_id; ?>">
```

and just use the jquery click function:

```
$('.like_link').click(function(){
     var id=$(this).attr("title");
     // Ajax-stuff
});
```

or something in that manner. I don't really intend on this being an answer, just informational.

Comment: Oh...and you can use the jquery .load method to refresh the page

Answer (score 0):

I did something similar in the past and modified it to an example for you.

Presuming your html with links looks like this:

```
<div id="allmylinks">
    <a href="toggle.php?link=foo">First link</a>
    <a href="toggle.php?link=bar">Second link</a>
</div>
```

```js
$("div#allmylinks a").click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    var link= $(this);
    $.get(
        $(this).attr('href'),
        function(data){
            console.log('Succesfull! '+data);
            link.attr('href',data);      // Set the new link
            $link.append(' was toggled');// Add some text
    });
    $(this).parents('div.entry-content').fadeOut('slow');
});
```

In toggle.php I had this:

```
if(isset($_REQUEST['link']))
    $link = $_REQUEST['link'];
else
    $link = "error";

// Validate link and process it
...

// If it's ajax
if(isset($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH']) && $_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH']==='XMLHttpRequest')
{
    // The new link
    echo 'toggle.php?link=toggled-'.$link;
}
// Not an ajax-request, redirect to previous page
else 
{
    header('Location: index.php');
    die();
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your code snippet examples.  I'm trying to see if I can recast my code to be more in line with your logic.  But the way I had it, in the HTML generated by the PHP loop (above) I was identifying the individual **links**, by each having a unique ID.  (I wasn't giving the containing div an ID.)  You can see examples of these links above, eg: `echo '<a href="#" id="linkid'.$step.'" title="Click to like this photo" class="like">&nbsp;</a>`

Comment: So the links in each iteration of the PHP loop take one of three forms (as per the _"Favourite exists..."_ comments above), but they always have unique IDs like "linkid1", "linkid2", "linkid3", etc.  I did it this way so that each **link** could be the target of the ajax processing (instead of one **div** like the "allmylinks" div in your example.  Can the js function be modified to work for each of these uniquely identified links?  Or is it necessary to target an ID of their containing div (there would be many of these per page)?

Comment: I guess, to be more in line with your logic, each link could be recast as `echo '<a href="processor.php?link='.$step.'&photoid='.$ThisID.'" title="Click to like this photo" class="like">&nbsp;</a>';` But then, my processing script (the equivalent of your toggle.php) needs to receive _two_ parameters to construct the new link - the `link` and the `photoid`.  (I could have used the `photid` as the `link` (so that they were the same), but it happens that the `photoid` often begins with a number, and since IDs can't begin with numbers, I made them separate.) I feel very close but not quite there!

Comment: I also realise that if I recast the data to be like yours, there would be a problem, since your js function takes just **one** ID.  I could give each containing div a unique ID, but there would still be many of these divs on the page.

Comment: If you modify the jquery-selector to `$("a.like")`, I think it will work as you would like.  You actually don't need the link-parameter, I used that to have something as a variable.

Comment: You willneed to change the url-parameter to processor.php and add some data to the request (the id).

Comment: _"You actually don't need the link-parameter"_ - sorry - which one do you mean? (head spinning now :)

Comment: I meant `toggle.php?link=foo`.  That link-parameter.  I just used that as an example for a variable.  You could just as wel turn that into `processor.php?photoid=id101`

Comment: It fails on the "If it's ajax" clause, returning the "Not an ajax-request, redirect to previous page".